# Почему не работает прокрутка мышкой в input?

Tags: javascript

```js
$('input[name="price"]').val(42.55);
$('input[name="price"]').on('mousewheel', function(e){
  let step = 0.01;
  let val = parseFloat($(this).val());
  if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
    $(this).val(val + step);
    console.log('Увеличение цены');
  }else{
    $(this).val(val - step);
    console.log('Уменьшение цены');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="price" value="">
```

Comment: Какого результата вы пытаетесь добиться? И что значит не работает, как должно работать?

Comment: @Max Watson, должно увеличиватся или уменьшатся значение в input колесиком мышки

Comment: `preventDefault` явно не хватает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вместо `mousewheel` установить `wheel`, или замени `on` на `bind`

Например:
`$('input[name="price"]').on('wheel', function(e){ ...`

Рабочий вариант:

```js
$('input[name="price"]').val(42.55);
$('input[name="price"]').on('wheel', function(e){
  let step = 0.01;
  let val = parseFloat($(this).val());
  if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
    $(this).val(val + step);
    console.log('Увеличение цены');
  }else{
    $(this).val(val - step);
    console.log('Уменьшение цены');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="price" value="">
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, а как пофиксить 42.67999999999997 ? немонимаю почему так сложение и вычитание работает

Comment: такие приколы у js, попробуй использовать toFixed()  для округления https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp